# How to create a trigger signal in vivado HLS

Tags: vivado, vivado-hls

I want to add a binary trigger signal for measurements to my vivado HLS IP.
The code looks as follows:

```
void subfunction1(const int a[10], const int b[10], int out[10]){
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    out[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}

void subfunction2(const int a[10], const int b[10], int out[10]){
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    out[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
}


void function(const int a[10], const int b[10], int out[10], bool *trigger){
  subfunction1(a, b, out);
  *trigger = true;
  subfunction2(out, b, out);
  *trigger = false
}

uint8_t top_level_fun(const int a[10], const int b[10], int out[10], bool *trigger){
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = a
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = b
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_memory port = out
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_fifo register port = trigger

#pragma HLS RESOURCE variable=a     core=ROM_1P_BRAM
#pragma HLS RESOURCE variable=b     core=ROM_1P_BRAM
#pragma HLS RESOURCE variable=out   core=RAM_1P_BROM

  function(a,b,out,trigger);
  return 0x01; // success
}
```

I want the `trigger` variable to be `0` normally and `1` during the execution of `subfunction2`. When I compile/co-simulate the code and view the results in the full wave viewer I see that the value of `trigger` never changes. How can I control the value of `trigger` during the execution of my code so that I can see this on the top level of my IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your trigger variable volatile:

```
void function([...], volatile bool *trigger)
uint8_t top_level_fun([...], volatile bool *trigger)
```

Otherwise the compiler will optimize away previous calls as it thinks they are unnecessary.

Please note the section on multi-access pointers in UG902 / [UG1399](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1399-vitis-hls/Multi-Access-Pointers-on-the-Interface):

> Designs that use pointers in the argument list of the top-level function (on the interface) need special consideration when multiple accesses are performed using pointers. Multiple accesses occur when a pointer is read from or written to multiple times in the same function.
>
> Using pointers which are accessed multiple times can introduce unexpected behavior after synthesis. In the following "bad" example pointer d_i is read four times and pointer d_o is written to twice: the pointers perform multiple accesses.

```
#include "pointer_stream_bad.h"

void pointer_stream_bad ( dout_t *d_o,  din_t *d_i) {
 din_t acc = 0;

 acc += *d_i;
 acc += *d_i;
 *d_o = acc;
 acc += *d_i;
 acc += *d_i;
 *d_o = acc;
}
```

> After synthesis this code will result in an RTL design which reads the input port once and writes to the output port once. As with any standard C/C++ compiler, Vitis HLS will optimize away the redundant pointer accesses.